# Where are the mouse settings in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: mouse, settings

After upgrade to 13.04 I cannot find mouse settings. There are only settings for Touchpad available in the 'Mouse & Touchpad' settings. The settings for mouse are missing (speed, acceleration) for any wireless mouse I tried. They appear only for wired mice. How can I fix this?

Comment: What mouse do you have?

Comment: The wireless mice are: 1x Anker mouse and 1x a mouse from Rapoo. Regardless of the mouse model, the pointer speed setting for wireless mice is always missing. I had them not attached at the same time. I also tested this with a Ubuntu 13.04 Live system to make sure it's not due to a corrupted install. Same problem on the Live system. A wireless keyboard though is correctly recognised. So it seems it's a bug.

I can only set the pointer speed via terminal:
xinput set-prop <device-id> "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" <value>

Comment: It could be driver issues. See if the company has Linux drivers for these.

Comment: It is definitely not a driver issue. Because on Ubuntu 12.10 the pointer speed setting was there for those same mice. But it vanished with the upgrade to 13.04.

Comment: I opened a bug report for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1174211

Answer (score 0):

They are unified now. The upper section, as the name suggests, is for both device types, the lower section is touchpad-specific.

Comment: No, they are not unified. The Touchpad speed settings have no effect on my mouse speed. When I have a corded mouse attached, there are two separate sections, one for Mouse, one for Touchpad:

http://i.imgur.com/QyQVpjM.png

When I have a wireless mouse attached, the pointer speed setting for the mouse is missing and only the one for Touchpad is there:

http://i.imgur.com/RsKbWQn.png